# PyGTK properties versus python properties

Tags: python, properties, pygtk, gobject

When deriving from a GObject class in PyGTK, you can define GObject properties like in C, using a `__gproperties__` dict, and `do_get_property`/`do_set_property` methods, as described here in [Sub-classing GObject in Python](http://www.pygtk.org/articles/subclassing-gobject/sub-classing-gobject-in-python.htm). Note that this was written before we had the `@property` decorator in Python.

GObject properties have the advantage that you can connect to the object's `notify::property-name` signal to receive a notification whenever the property changes. Other than that, is there any good reason to use GObject properties instead of Python's `@property` decorator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use them? With the [simplified version](http://blogs.gnome.org/johan/2007/04/30/simplified-gobject-properties/) provided by the
Python bindings, defining GObject properties is not that different to
defining Python properties.

Having said that, there are a couple of advantages other than
notification. The one that I've made use of in the past is property
setting in gtk.Builder files. For example, in your UI file,

```
<object class="GtkImage" id="image">
  <property name="stock">gtk-missing-image</property>
</object>
```

sets the `stock` property on the Image object when constructed by the
Builder class; if you use GObject properties in
your custom widgets, you can take advantage of this too. This behaviour will be even
more useful with the advent of [property binding support in Glade](http://www.google-melange.com/gsoc/proposal/review/google/gsoc2011/denisw/1).

Another potential advantage is GObject properties' min/max limits and
default values for integers and floats, which can sometimes be useful for
UI-related properties.

Comment: I did not know about the simplified version! Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

> Other than that, is there any good reason to use GObject properties instead of Python's @property decorator?

Not really. There's a lot of boilerplate for them, so unless I need the `notify` signals, I write whatever I need in Python.

Having said that, it's fairly common that I'll think "I don't need notifications for this property" and then realise "actually, I don't need this property at all, then."